# Objective C and parse.com queries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using parse to create simple API service, and i want to use queries on this.

In tutorial there is a section that describes how this is done in python actually really simple.

```
params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
   "playerName": "Sean Plott",
   "cheatMode": False
 })})
```

While in python it might be simple line to do this, how do I do this in objective C? Do i really first make dictionary, then JSON encode it, transform it into string and then url encode it?

Comment: Have you looked at Parse's objective c documentation?  Worked through their tutorials?

Comment: Actually this is from their tutorial

Comment: Their iOS tutorial?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: iOS tutorial is about their iOS SDK, i want to connect to their API via AFNetwork etc..., no SDK.

Comment: So you want to use their Rest API from iOS without using their iOS framework? Why?

Comment: Correct, but it seems whey harder then it should be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90656/discussion-between-paulw11-and-megamanx).